# Unable to send String object in Dataprovider in testng

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I was trying to feed values from a notepad file to a test method in testng.

I had multiple values in notepad file such as

uname1
pwd1
uname2
pwd2 and so on...

I have written following code for my DataProvider method

```
List<String> list=FileRead.doRead(); //This is method returning list of values from txt file
String[] array=list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
String uname=null, pwd=null;
for (int x=0; x<array.length; x++)
{
    uname=array[x];
    pwd=array[x+1];
}
Object obj[][]={{uname, pwd}};      
return obj;
```

I want to ask whether we can pass string object to Object array or not? because I was getting error on it. If yes can you show me. also with the approach I have mentioned I was getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.
my test method has following code

```
@Test(dataProvider="mydp")
public void testCase1(String uname, String pwd) throws FileNotFoundException,
IOException
{
    getLoginDetails(uname, pwd);
}
```

Please provide me solution for the above

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a String array.  However, the real problem it's a 1D array, not a 2D array.  This code will turn it into a 2D array.

```
Object[] arr = FileRead.doRead().toArray();
Object[][] data = new Object[arr.length/2][2];
for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x+=2){
   data[x/2][0]=arr[x];
   data[x/2][1]=arr[x+1];
}
return data;
```

Comment: Thank you very much MrTi. It would be great if you could explain to me the whole code. Thanks again

Comment: Nathan Merrill, can you help me with this please?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198989/how-to-iterate-an-array-of-string-and-return-it/33199560?noredirect=1#comment54204484_33199560